# How to maintain aspect ratio of responsive card image with minimum height?

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Using react-bootstrap how can you make a Card background image fill the whole card, yet enforce a minimum height without squashing the image?  I want Bootstrap to downsize the image until the minimum height is reached, then crop the image if required to maintain the minimum height, all while maintaining the image's aspect ratio (ie: without squashing the image).

[image]

Comment: we need some code to work with.

Comment: Any react-bootstrap Card example that does this will work.  Here's an example of something that fails.

    <Card style={{ minHeight: 700, maxHeight: 1200, minWidth: 400 }}>
        <Card.Img src={bg}  alt="Card image" style={{ minHeight: 700, maxHeight: 1200  }} />
    </Card>

Comment: can you please use a sandbox and provide us the link it will show a working demo which is amazing and will help us understand the problem. 

https://codesandbox.io/

that's the website. use it to add your code and share the link. :) so we can see a working demo

Answer (score 2):

Use this things in your code:

```css
   .item img {

    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    height:100%;
    object-fit: cover; // here is the key

   }
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp